# How to apply assersion on varying response in soapui

Tags: soapui, assertion

Is there any way to apply assertion on the Varying responses of the same request?
Project structure is like this:

.Test Request

..DataSource

...Test Request

....Data Loop

I am storing a specific node's value from 1st request in the data source and iterating on those values in the 2nd request. Each time response is different. Now I wanted to add some assertion to verify the response of the second request. Pl. let me know if need any other information.

Comment: If you know the response in advance you can read that in a property and in the assertion mention the property.

Comment: Thanks for reply Abhishek. I have total 41 values getting stored in the Datasource and Response is changing for each of these values. I wanted to apply a message content assertion for every response.

Comment: did that solve your problem?

Comment: No, because response is changing for each of the value.

Comment: Do you in advance what the response is going to be?

Comment: Yes, I know the response in advance.

Comment: Store those values in a file and when you need to assert, just read the value from there..If these values are in a database you can put a jdbc step after the query is run and verify that the data in the db and from the response are same.

Comment: @abhishek Suppose I have 3 responses having following values to compare.. 1st response : 1, 2, 3. 2nd Response: 4,5,6. 3rd Response: 7,8,9. Now I have stored these values in a excel file in different sheets then what should be the approach to compare these values in a data loop. Is there any script of any way in SoapUI Pro? How would I know which sheet should be compared with the response. Hope you got my question. Thanks.

Comment: Could you add more detail to your question. Post some real data samples. Or if possible post the algorithm how the response is derived from the input.